# Java: how to analyze an input (patterns?)

Tags: java, regex, user-input, lexer

I hope you can help me with a java program I´m writing.

I have to analize the inputs that a user gives to my programm which can be of three types:

1) simple number: "x"
2) two numbers using AND or OR: "AND(x, y)" or "OR(x, y)"
3) a combination of the previous two types: for example "AND(x, OR(y, AND(z, AND(t, w))))".

The grammar should be: S -> AND(S, S)|OR(S, S)|number;

I´ve thought on using patterns but i don't know how to create one like this.
This is what i wrote, but it's obviously wrong:

> `public static void analizeInpute(String input) {`
>
> > ```
> >    Pattern patternAND = Pattern.compile("AND( (.*?), (AND()*(.*?))");   
> >    Pattern patternOR = Pattern.compile("OR( (.*?), (OR()*(.*?))");  
> >    Matcher matcherAND = patternAND.matcher(input);  
> >    Matcher matcherOR = patternOR.matcher(input);  
> >    if (matcherAND.find()) {  
> >            //do the AND operation i have to do. 
> >    }
> >    else if (matcherOR.find()) {  
> >            //do the OR operation i have to do.  
> >    }
> >    else {    
> >    }
> > ```
> >
> > }

Can someone help me to write the lexer & pattern?
Thanks in advice!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I´ve written a method that splits the input in a string and reads the first word. It checks if it is a number or AND or OR. If it is AND or OR it reads the next two words. But it is obviously not working/not solving my issue in the 3rd case.

Comment: Would you mind adding the code for the professionals here as no one'll answer such a broad question. Please add code and ask what it is not able to achieve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @DThought about Lexer, but do not agree at all about using regular expressions. Regular expressions are not the right tool for the job. They're meant to understand [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chomsky-hierarchy.svg), but [context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) like what you have are superset of that. See illustrative diagram from Wikipedia:

[image]

Now, most regular expression implementations today do more than just regular languages, but the main point still stands - it's not the right tool. The extensions are hacky and you'll end up doing complex workarounds for things that are considerably simpler to solve in other ways.

---

In your task, you'd start with a tokenizer that would tokenize any input into tokens that you support - AND, OR and numbers. Then you'd implement a lexer.

About implementing a lexer, see [Adobe.com: How To Write A Simple Lexical Analyzer](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/How_To_Write_A_Simple_Lexical_Analyzer_or_Parser), as that's a bit more than would fit into a simple answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you've created is a start. You need to write something that's called a "Lexer", that is capable of understanding the grammar of the language you're inputing. I'd start with having a way to determine whether the next part of the string is a number, or an AND( ? , ?) or an OR ( ? , ?)  [these parts are called 'Tokens'] - whereas ? can be any token,  you must balance the ( and ) to have it correct), and fed into your algorithm recursivley